# Add Group Calendar as Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, exchange

I have a Group calendar made of an ordinary SharePoint Calendar 
and an Exchange Calendar.

I would like to add this group calendar as a web part.
Unfortunately when I add a web part with my calendar only the events of the Sharepoint Calendar show up.

What could I do to make the Exchange Calendar events visible to in the web part?

I am using SharePoint 2013 on premises.

Answer (score 0):

I  have found that I have to set Calendar view to the web part
as suggested here:
[enter link description here](http://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/calendar-overlay-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-ootb-master-calendar/)